# How To Remove List From Another List In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here I have two list `var userListFromFriendTable = mainService.GetUserFromFriend(ChattingUserName);` and `var getAllUserFromMessageUserTable = mainService.GetalluserfromMessageUser();` whose implementation are
given below. 
Now what is want is to remove all the `Friend table FriendRequestReceiverName column data` of `userListFromFriendTable`  list from `MessageUser table MessageUserName column` of `getAllUserFromMessageUserTable` list.
Any help will be grate

```
    public List<Friend> GetUserFromFriend(string chattingUserName)
    {
        var checkUser = uow.Repository<Friend>().FindBy(x => x.FriendRequestSenderName.ToLower() == chattingUserName.ToLower()).ToList();
        return checkUser;
    }
    public List<MessageUser> GetalluserfromMessageUser()
    {
        var checkUser = uow.Repository<MessageUser>().GetAll().ToList();
        return checkUser;
    }
```

```
public class Friend
{
    public int FriendId { get; set; }
    public string FriendRequestSenderName { get; set; }
    public string FriendRequestReceiverName { get; set; }
    public int IsConfirmed { get; set; }
}
public class MessageUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MessageUserName { get; set; }
    public int IsFriend { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hey please clear your question on which logic you want to remove the items from `userListFromFriendTable`  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var names=userListFromFriendTable.Select(i=> i.FriendRequestReceiverName) 
  .OfType<string>()
 .ToArray();

getAllUserFromMessageUserTable.RemoveAll(r => names.Contains( r.MessageUserName );
```

Comment: Thank you it workd , but can you please tell me can I assign getAllUserFromMessageUserTable.RemoveAll(r => names.Contains( r.MessageUserName ); list to  public List<MessageUser> messageUsersList = new List<MessageUser>();

Comment: yes , you can do this way -  var  messageUsersList = getAllUserFromMessageUserTable.RemoveAll(.....