# How to update record if record already exists EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda

I need to update db record if already `MemberNumber` is there and if that particular member not in the DB I need to insert record.

My code is as follows.

```
public class MemberDto
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public string MemberNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

In the Member table, `MemberId` is primary key.

```
public Member(IClientContextFactory contextFactory, IMapper mapper, int tenantId)
{
    this.context = contextFactory.GetContext(tenantId);
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

public void InsertMembers(List<MemberDto> members)
{
    List<EFModel.ClientData.Member> membersInEfModel = new List<EFModel.ClientData.Member>();
    mapper.Map<List<MemberDto>, List<EFModel.ClientData.Member>>(members, membersInEfModel);

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var lastUserRecord = context.Members.OrderByDescending(x => x.MemberId).FirstOrDefault();
        var lastUserID = lastUserRecord.MemberId;

        foreach (var member in membersInEfModel)
        {
            member.MemberId = ++lastUserID;
            var existedMember = context.Members.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MemberNumber == member.MemberNumber);
            if (existedMember == null)
            {
                context.Members.Add(member);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

The above code is getting me following error:

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

To avoid that I changed this line `context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;` into  `context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Added;` But by doing that, **Even if the database already has that `MemberNumber` , the relevant value will be entered**. How can I avoid this? What did I do wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entry() returns an  instance of the entity that is kept in dbContext.  For each tracked entity, Ef  keeps track of  state of the entity (Unchanged, Modified, Added, or Delete). It also keeps current and original values of properties. This is the best place to modify original entity. You can get or set the most of the entity properties.

```
 var existedMember = context.Members.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MemberNumber == member.MemberNumber);
 if (existedMember == null)
  {
      context.Members.Add(member);
   }
     else
   {
    member.MemberId=existedMember.MemberId;
    Context.Entry(existedMember).CurrentValues.SetValues(member);
   }
```

Comment: now I'm getting this error, `The property 'MemberId' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.` I think this because I trying to update MemberId? when calling  `InsertMembers`. I'm getting `MemberId` as 0 so, thats why i trying to set `MemberId` manually.

Comment: @thomsan I added some changes. Pls try again.

Comment: Awesome, its working well. can please explain me what does the else part, and one more thing. I have records more than 100000, some time this makes my program getting stuck. is there any good solution to improve above code

Comment: Thanks sir, can u please give an idea to handle huge list. as I mentioned in above comment, when using more than 100000, getting stuck. is that happen because of the `TransactionScope`? do I really need to use TransactionScope here?

Comment: @thomsan I usualy use -  using var transaction = Context.Database.BeginTransaction();   But in your case  you need a transaction only if it is very important  to update or add the whole list of members together.  In this case if something happens only with one record all database records will be left unchanged and all new ones will not be added. But if you can manage to add or update failed records  of your list later, you don't need any trasaction and everything will going much faster .

Comment: And you can check this my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676919/how-to-remove-list-from-another-list-in-c-sharp/66677188#66677188  . You can create list of records that should be added and should be updated using this tip . You will need only one trip to do this, instead of checking each record.  After this you can use for example AddRange method to add all the records together.

Comment: you mean hear I don't need TransactionScope? is it sir? if i do it, it will much efficient than current one?

Comment: Sir I looked u given link answer, but I have no idea how I add implement that logic into my code. can u please give me an answer please

Comment: TransactionScope it is very old syntax and you shouldn't use it  with EF.  I don't know if you need begingtransaction since I don't know what is your goal. As I explained you already you have to make this desicion.

Comment: You will need a big chunk of code. I can't post it in the comments.

Comment: I think you have to post another question with updated code and ask about the performance  impovement.

Comment: Maybe another people will want to participate too